# How to hide bootbox.js modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I want to hide all of my [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) modals. I currently have 2 modal and after I click on Cancel, I want to hide the all other modals.

Here's my code:

```
$('#table-grid').delegate(".requestBill", "click", function () { // store the checked checkbox ticket_id into array 
const prop_id = $(this).data('prop_id');
bootbox.prompt({
  title: "Request Bill",
  inputType: 'textarea',
  placeholder: 'Enter Additional Message',
  value: 'I am requesting an RPT Bill.',
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      label: 'Submit'
    },
    cancel: {
      label: 'Cancel',


    }
  },
  callback: function (result) {
    if (result == null) {
      $.toast({
              heading: 'Note',
              text: 'Cannot request bill without describing reason(s)',
              icon: 'error',
              loader: false,
              stack: false,
              position: 'top-center',
              allowToastClose: false,
              bgColor: '#f0ad4e',
              textColor: 'white',
            });
    } else if (result == "") {
      $.toast({
              heading: 'Note',
              text: 'Cannot request bill without describing reason(s)',
              icon: 'error',
              loader: false,
              stack: false,
              position: 'top-center',
              allowToastClose: false,
              bgColor: '#f0ad4e',
              textColor: 'white',
            });


    } else {
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("prop_id", prop_id);
      fd.append("content", result);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "Main_declaration/request_bill",
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
          $(".requestBill").attr('disabled', true)
        },
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.success == 1) {
            $.toast({
              heading: 'Success',
              text: data.message,
              icon: 'success',
              loader: true,
              stack: false,
              position: 'top-center',
              allowToastClose: false,
              bgColor: '#5cb85c',
              textColor: 'white',
            });
          } else {
            $.toast({
              heading: 'Note',
              text: data.message,
              icon: 'error',
              loader: false,
              stack: false,
              position: 'top-center',
              allowToastClose: false,
              bgColor: '#f0ad4e',
              textColor: 'white',
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

});

What would be the syntax to hide bootbox modals(All modals)?

Comment: Have you tried the [Bootstap events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)? Maybe that works.

Comment: `bootbox.hideAll();`. As noted in the [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-public-functions).

Answer (score 2):

$('.bootbox.modal').modal('hide') should do the trick for you

Comment: Should i put it on cancel?

Comment: You must be triggering some sort of callback on click of cancel. Put this in there. So when you click cancel, the modal would be hidden as you want

Comment: Like this? cancel: {
     label: 'Cancel',
     callback:function(){$('.bootbox.modal').modal('hide');}
     

    }

Comment: Yes, also attach the relevant class name that would identify the cancel button

Comment: i did cancel: {
     label: 'Cancel',
     className: "btn-sm btn-cancel",
     callback:function(){$('.bootbox.modal').hide('hide');}
     

    }

Comment: Can you confirm if your callback is being triggered? If not, that is the source of the issue. In className, can you have just one class for now and check if that works

Answer (score 2):

You should use next method:

```
bootbox.hideAll();
```

Documentation reference: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-function-hideAll